# ios catalyst My app supports multiple windows. After multiple windows are abnormally closed, reopen the app and multiple windows appear

Tags: ios, objective-c, mac-catalyst

My IOS app supports Mac. Open multiple windows in the Mac. When these windows close abnormally, multiple windows will be loaded after re running the app. I don't want to. When re running the project, it should load one window every time

Comment: how should we know? Is it document based with NSDocumentController? If so, discard the documents that are not of interest.